# Chrome extension won't redirect to localhost with port number

Tags: redirect, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I built a Chrome extension (manifest V3) that has dynamic domain redirect functionality. In general it works as expected, even if I redirect to `localhost`. However, if I attempt to redirect to localhost with a port number, e.g. `localhost:4000`, it adds the rule with no errors (as is confirmed by running `chrome.declarativeNetRequest.getDynamicRules()` in the service worker console), but doesn't redirect.

Here's how I add the rule in the background service worker:

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
  addRules: [
    {
      id: 1,
      priority: 1,
      action: {type: 'redirect', redirect: {transform: {host: 'localhost:4000'}}},
      condition: {resourceTypes: ['main_frame'], requestDomains: ['example.com']}
    }
  ]
});
```

I would like to know if this is expected functionality for whatever reason or is it a bug. Additionally, If anyone could help with a work around, that would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The `port` should be [specified separately](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#type-URLTransform) AFAICT.

Comment: @wOxxOm That's it, thank you. If you'd like you can post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question here, based on what @wOxxOm correctly pointed out in a comment, as it may be useful to soemone else.

When forwarding to a domain with an specified port, the port needs to be specified sepearately.

The corrected code would be as follows:

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
  addRules: [
    {
      id: 1,
      priority: 1,
      action: {type: 'redirect', redirect: {transform: {host: 'localhost', port: '4000'}}},
      condition: {resourceTypes: ['main_frame'], requestDomains: ['example.com']}
    }
  ]
})
```